# Create Associative Array with Foreach, Insert into existing Associative Array

Tags: php, arrays, amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

**Hello.**

I currently have a problem with the AWS Route-53 API. To create a record you need to call a function, which itself needs an array of inputs.

I want to create a record set here and for that I have some POST values. One of them, `$_POST['record_value']`, is a textarea and has multiple lines. I loop through them. This is to enable multiple values for one record. The code is as follows when you hardcode it as one value in `ResourceRecords`;

```
$result = $this->route53->changeResourceRecordSets([
            'ChangeBatch' => [
                'Changes' => [
                    [
                        'Action' => 'CREATE',
                        'ResourceRecordSet' => [
                            'Name' => $recordName,
                            'ResourceRecords' => [
                               [
                                   'Value' => $recordValue
                               ],
                            ],
                            'TTL' => $recordTtl,
                            'Type' => $recordType,
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
                'Comment' => 'Routing Record Set',
            ],
            'HostedZoneId' => $this->zone,
        ]);
```

Hower. I want to make `ResourceRecords` dynamically. For every line in the textarea I need a new set of the following part of the code;

```
  [
     'Value' => $recordValue
  ],
```

What I thought is the following;

```
 $newData = [];
        foreach(explode("\r\n", $recordValue) as $valLine) {
            $newData[] = ["Value" => $valLine];
        }

        $result = $this->route53->changeResourceRecordSets([
            'ChangeBatch' => [
                'Changes' => [
                    [
                        'Action' => 'CREATE',
                        'ResourceRecordSet' => [
                            'Name' => $recordName,
                            'ResourceRecords' => [
                               $newData
                            ],
                            'TTL' => $recordTtl,
                            'Type' => $recordType,
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
                'Comment' => 'Routing Record Set',
            ],
            'HostedZoneId' => $this->zone,
        ]);
```

However, this seems to return an exception: `Found 1 error while validating the input provided for the ChangeResourceRecordSets operation:↵[ChangeBatch][Changes][0][ResourceRecordSet][ResourceRecords][0] must be an associative array. Found array(1).`

Am I building the array wrong or am I doing this wrong alltogether?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$newData` is already an array, you don't need to wrap it in another array.

```
'ResourceRecords' => $newData,
```

Comment: Ah. One array around another array. A bit too much. Thanks.

Comment: Except that if you look at the hard-coded example, `ResourceRecords` is an array of arrays (god I hate how much JSON has ruined PHP). `'ResourceRecords' => [['Value' => $recordValue],],`

Comment: @Anthony `$newData` is an array of arrays. He was creating an array of array of arrays.

Comment: Nice Catch! Totally didn't pick up on `$newData[] = ["Value" => $valLine];` as an array being pushed to an array. Again, I blame JSON. So many nested arrays.

Comment: @Anthony I don't see what that has to do with JSON. It's just a design decision the API creator made about how to organize the data. It's no harder to use an array of strings in JSON.